# Applying style sheets in pyqt

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, stylesheet, pyqt4

If i apply a property to a parent widget it is automatically applied for child widgets too.. Is there any way of preventing this?? For example if i set background color as white in a dialog the button,combo boxes and scroll bars looks white as it lacks it native look(have to say it's unpleasant & ugly).. Is there any way that i can apply the stylesheets only to a parent widget not to it's children???

Experts help please..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a solution..

Instead of using

```
self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                                    "border:1px solid rgb(255, 170, 255);")
```

use specifically using selector types..

```
self.groupBox.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { background-color: rgb(255, 255,\
255); border:1px solid rgb(255, 170, 255); }")
```

This solves the problem..